# How to construct a zip file with libzip

Tags: c++, pugixml, libzip

I try to create a compressed file and insert an xml file in it using two libraries (pugixml / libzip), everything goes without error, but when I open the xml file, the encoding at the beginning of the file is weird :

**Main.cpp :**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <zip.h>
#include <pugixml.hpp>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    auto document = std::unique_ptr<pugi::xml_document>(new pugi::xml_document);
    pugi::xml_node declNode = document->prepend_child(pugi::node_declaration);
    declNode.append_attribute("version") = "1.0";
    declNode.append_attribute("encoding") = "UTF-8";
    declNode.append_attribute("standalone") = "yes";

    pugi::xml_node rootNode = document->append_child("Document");
    rootNode.append_child("Files");


    int err = 0;
    zip_t* zip = zip_open("test.zip", ZIP_CREATE, &err);
    {
        {
            std::stringstream ss;
            document->save(ss, "  ");
            std::string buffer = ss.str();
            auto src = zip_source_buffer_create(buffer.c_str(),buffer.length(),0,0);
            zip_file_add(zip,"Document.xml",src,ZIP_FL_ENC_UTF_8);
        }
    }
    zip_close(zip);

    return 0;
}
```

**Document.xml :**

```
~U Ä U rsion="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Document>
   <Files />
</Document>
```

**Hex :**
[image: hex]

Comment: Looks good. *when I open the xml file* - that file opener seems to be unable to work with utf-8 bom. Please show the file content in hex.

Comment: @273K i've updated with a screenshot

Comment: I see you are right, the file content is broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The posted program has undefined behaviour due to reading already freed memory.

In the example you posted the `zip_source_t` gets creatd with `freep = 0`, so you need to make sure that the provided buffer remains valid for the entire lifetime of the `zip_source_t` object:
[zip_source_buffer](https://libzip.org/documentation/zip_source_buffer.html)

> `zip_source_t * zip_source_buffer_create(const void *data, zip_uint64_t len, int freep, zip_error_t *error);`
>
> The functions `zip_source_buffer()` and `zip_source_buffer_create()` create a zip source from the buffer data of size *len*. If *freep* is non-zero, the buffer will be freed when it is no longer needed.
> ***data* must remain valid for the lifetime of the created source**.
> The source can be used to open a zip archive from.

`zip_file_add()` (if successfull) will take ownership of the source you give it, but note that it is not required to free the source immediately - it could for example store it within the `zip_t`.

As it is currently implemented `zip_file_add()` does not free the `zip_source_t` - it instead hangs onto it and writes it out once you call `zip_close()`. So your buffer needs to remain valid for the entire remaining lifetime of the `zip_t` object - in this case this is until the call to `zip_close()`.

If you rewrite your example to keep the `std::string buffer;` alive until after you've closed the `zip_t` the resulting file should be correct:

```cpp
zip_t* zip = zip_open("test.zip", ZIP_CREATE, &err);
std::stringstream ss;
document->save(ss, "  ");
std::string buffer = ss.str();
auto src = zip_source_buffer_create(buffer.c_str(),buffer.length(),0,0);
zip_file_add(zip,"Document.xml",src,ZIP_FL_ENC_UTF_8);
zip_close(zip); // lifetime of zip_t ends here (which will also end the lifetime of the zip_source_t)

// lifetime of buffer ends at end of scope
```

---

##### Recommendation

There is no way to know how long the `zip_source_t` will be alive (it's reference-counted), and so it's not easy to know for how long exactly you need to keep your buffer alive.

So I would recommend allocating the memory for the `zip_source_t` separately with `malloc()` and passing `freep=1` to `zip_source_buffer_create()`.

That way the buffer will remain valid as long as the `zip_source_t` is alive.

Comment: Thanks for this answer - apparently the fact that the `zip_file_add()` is not synchronous is rather confusing... also forces having large buffers in memory potentially. Seems 'bad' design.

Comment: @Emanuele I'd say that the documentation around `zip_source_buffer_create` and its `freep` parameter is insufficient - the fact that `zip_source_t`'s are [reference counted](https://libzip.org/documentation/zip_source.html) is not mentioned there, and also the fact that some functions might unexpectedly keep the source alive (i.e. there's no mention of this on the [`zip_file_add()` documentation site](https://libzip.org/documentation/zip_file_add.html))

Comment: @Emanuele But it's understandable why it has been implemented that way - imagine you're opening an existing 50GB zip file and want to update 5 small files within it; if `zip_file_add()` would not save the `zip_source_t` for later it would need to write out each change immediately - so instead of 1 rewrite when closing the zip file you would now need 5 - once for each `zip_file_add()` call. So at least in the case of large zip files it's a lot more efficient to just do all the work at the end, instead of doing them one-by-one.

Comment: @Emanuele if you don't want to store all the data you want for a file in memory you can use [`zip_source_function_create()`](https://libzip.org/documentation/zip_source_function_create.html) instead of `zip_source_buffer_create()` - this allows you to stream the required data once libzip is ready to write the source - you'd only need to implement a *read source*, so only implementing `ZIP_SOURCE_OPEN`, `ZIP_SOURCE_READ`, `ZIP_SOURCE_CLOSE` and `ZIP_SOURCE_STAT` should suffice.

Comment: I understand your points, still I'd rather have a _sync_ api (perhaps in addition) so that I would be able to do the work predictably - I get the optimizations etc etc, but still this is also _not_ good to for example implement a progress report.
Also yes, the API is poorly documented.